# NSEntityDescription error while fetching the core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data, nsentitydescription

here is my function for fetching core data

```
- (void)fetchRecords {   

    // Define our table/entity to use  
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Fugitive" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];   

    // Setup the fetch request  
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];  
    [request setEntity:entity];   

    // Define how we will sort the records  
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];  
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];  
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];  
    [sortDescriptor release];   

    // Fetch the records and handle an error  
    NSError *error;  
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];   

    if (!mutableFetchResults) {  
        NSLog(@"Error in Fetching Result");
        // Handle the error.  
        // This is a serious error and should advise the user to restart the application  
    }

    // Save our fetched data to an array
    [self setFugitiveArray: mutableFetchResults];
    [mutableFetchResults release];
    [request release];
}
```

i got following error while running the program   'Program received signal: "SIGABRT"'

```
iBountyHunter[1013:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'Fugitive''
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x011005a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01254313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreData                            0x00e2aebb +[NSEntityDescription entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:] + 187
    3   iBountyHunter                       0x000030e6 -[FugitiveListViewController fetchRecords] + 86
    4   iBountyHunter                       0x00003411 -[FugitiveListViewController viewDidLoad] + 289
    5   UIKit                               0x00375f26 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1556
    6   UIKit                               0x00377ab7 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 168
    7   UIKit                               0x0017d17a -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFile] + 172
    8   UIKit                               0x0017dcf4 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 291
    9   UIKit                               0x00188617 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1533
    10  UIKit                               0x00180abf -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 71
    11  UIKit                               0x00185f2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    12  GraphicsServices                    0x01c48992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x010e1944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x01041cf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0103ef83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0103e840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0103e761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    18  UIKit                               0x0017d7d2 -[UIApplication _run] + 623
    19  UIKit                               0x00189c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    20  iBountyHunter                       0x00002519 main + 121
    21  iBountyHunter                       0x00002495 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Comment: is your managedObjectContext == 0x0 ???

Comment: yes it shows 0X0 ??? so what could be the problem

Comment: ok at where did you declare it ?

Comment: in .h file and i have also declared a property and synthesized and also written code to dealloc...

Comment: then you should show that part of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have declare in app delegate then you should check it like :

```
if (managedObjectContext == nil) 
{ 
        managedObjectContext = [(YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
        NSLog(@" %@",  managedObjectContext);
}
```

Comment: after keeping this before NSEntityDescription.... i still got (null) in managedObjectContext??

Comment: @DShah What was the change you did in xib ?

Comment: @Signcodeindie: There is no change in XIB. Its just a visual representation. No need to change the views.